How to allocate memory in NASM without C functions (x64)?
So I'm using NASM on linux and I was curious how this is done. All the info I can find online uses functions from C like malloc(). Can this be done purely with assembly code? Perhaps via a system call?
Thanks.

This looks like a question for Stack Overflow; it's purely about engineering and how a specific system works (x86-64 Linux), not science.  Flagged for migration.

Are you still using the C standard library, even though you are not writing in C? Then you can just call malloc. It's the same with functions like printf.

@user20574 I'm aware that this is doable but I'm trying to handle everything in only assembly

You have to decide where your boundaries are - the Linux kernel is written in C anyways. You want to use system calls (which call into the C code in Linux) directly for everything, no libraries in your program? Then look at mmap.

On Linux you can use the brk syscall to extend you data segment.
First call brk(0) to find the break point and then extend your data segment every time you run out of memory.
Another syscall to look into would be mmap, malloc uses both.
You can find a very nice explanation (and a simple memory manager written in assembly) in Chapter 9 of this book, though it might be a bit inaccessible since it uses x86 and AT&T syntax instead of x64 and NASM.
But the general idea should still be applicable to x64 assembly.
Happy hacking :]

Specifically mmap(..., MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, ...) with an fd = -1 will allocate fresh pages without needing to actually open /dev/zero like some early Unix systems needed to do.  On Linux, strace /bin/ls will show the system calls it makes, which includes some such mmap calls.

I was under the impression that malloc exclusively used mmap. I guess it only happens for allocations less than a megabyte
